# Using Unity Project Tango plugin with a second plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, artoolkit

Does anyone have any practical examples of combining Google's project tango unity plugin with another 3rd party plugin?  I've not found any yet.

I am trying to get the Project Tango Unity plugin working with ARToolkit Unity plugin for Android, but I'm extremely new to Android development.

I have tried merging the AndroidManifest.xml for each plugin but this hasn't worked.  I'm now looking to incorporate the tango jar files into the ARToolkit UnityARPlayer project, and extend the UnityARPlayer class - except, knowing so little (and have little time), I am quite out of my depth.  It would be good if there was a practical example of this being done with another Unity plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Adding ARToolkit Marker tracking into Tango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934359/adding-artoolkit-marker-tracking-into-tango)

A little late, But I wrote this showing how to Add ARToolkit processing for TANGO.  There's an example Unity project at the bottom.

Extending the UnityARPlayer class was the right direction, I took the GoogleUnityPlayer and extended it for the ARToolkit stuff.  Sorry but I haven't tidied or documented the code at all, so it is probably not a good reference for generally adding second plugins.